# Section heading with landscape environment

Tags: landscape

I wonder how you can get your section heading sideways above a sideways figure in Latex, like in the picture below. Can someone help me?

This is my code for the figure, using the landscape environment.

```
\newgeometry{top=5mm, bottom=5mm}
\begin{landscape} 
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=1.6\textwidth]{Prices.jpg}
     \caption{Caption}
     \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444982/113546)  can give you some inspiration.